# How do I get Ubuntu 16.04 to generate a type 3 DUID instead of a Type 1 DUID?

Tags: 16.04, dhclient, dhcpv6

I'm trying to get IPv6 set up on a client (no GUI) using DHCPv6. It appears that Ubuntu by default configures `dhclient` to generate a Type 1 DUID (LLT) - an ID based on the mac address and the time of boot.

Instead I'd like it to generate a Type 3 DUID (LL) - an ID based purely on the MAC address. This will create a static DUID which I can then use to get the DHCPv6 server to send client-specific configuration.

I have been unable however to trace through where Ubuntu calls `dhclient` to pass in the `-D` argument to tell it to generate a Type 3 DUID. From what I can tell `systemd` calls out to the `ifup@.service` script, but I can't find where abouts in that script, or the scripts it calls out to, `dhclient` is called.